# Eggs and Floors Puzzle - Alternate

Tags: algorithms, optimization, searching

Recently I've run across the "Two eggs, 100 floors" problem:

You are given two eggs, and access to a 100-story building. Both eggs are identical. The aim is to find out the highest floor from which an egg will not break when dropped out of a window from that floor. If an egg is dropped and does not break, it is undamaged and can be dropped again. However, once an egg is broken, that’s it for that egg.

If an egg breaks when dropped from floor n, then it would also have broken from any floor above that. If an egg survives a fall, then it will survive any fall shorter than that.

This page (http://datagenetics.com/blog/july22012/index.html) explains how to solve this puzzle very well, but I've run across an extension that asks for an algorithm for what floor to drop the first egg from.

When considering this for the 2 eggs, 100 floors problem, I found that the first floor to throw the egg from (14) matched the minimum number of throws required to find the floor for which the egg doesn't break from when thrown.

However, when extending this to 3 eggs, the total number of throws needed becomes 9, but that doesn't mean that the FIRST egg throw needs to be made from the 9th floor. Intuitively, it would need to be from a higher floor than 14.

Thus, my question is not "how do you minimize the number of throws" as the original puzzle states. My question is: How do you determine what floor to drop the FIRST egg from when you have n eggs and k floors? Is it possible to find a generalized approach for that?

Comment: "How do you minimize the number of throws" - wouldn't it make much more sense to minimize the amount of walking you need to do? Walking up to floor 99 is a lot of work.

Comment: Any reasonable solution to the puzzle would give a complete algorithm, and in particular will tell you where to drop the first egg from. Perhaps the solutions you found aren't good enough.

Comment: Assume you have as many eggs as needed. What would be the ideal search algorithm?

Comment: `How do you determine what floor to drop the FIRST egg from when you have n eggs and k floors?` This is why I never know if this (extended) puzzle isn't _math_.

Comment: @Raphael If we have as many eggs as needed, a binary search method would be the most ideal. Thus it would be totalFloors/2 for the first throw. If the egg doesn't break, then go to the higher half of floors and repeat. If it goes, go with the lower half and repeat.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus While that is true, none of the algorithms provide the set of correct optimal answers. For 3 eggs for example, I believe there could be a range of correct answers (I cannot prove that yet). Even though the algorithms online may show the intermediate floors of where to drop the egss, none give the range of possible solutions for each drop before being left with 2 eggs. This is what I'm trying to solve.

Comment: Right, that is provably optimal. Now, what would you do if you had only *one* egg? Combine the two extremes.

Comment: I read the website you link to; it seems fairly complete. In particular, the recursive approach for computing the minimum number of drops can easily be extended to also return the tree of floors.

Comment: @Raphael With one egg, we have to go floor by floor starting from floor 1. I understand the approach for 1 egg, 2 eggs, and many eggs, but I'm still unable to combine everything into one complete solution.
Can you explain how the number of drops can be easily extended to return the tree of floors?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Algorithm to find maximum number of floors you can check with N eggs and D maximum drops](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/64093/algorithm-to-find-maximum-number-of-floors-you-can-check-with-n-eggs-and-d-maxim)

Comment: First you need to decide what you want to minimise: Average number of drops, maximum number of drops, average number of stairs walked, maximum number of stairs walked. You calculate these quantities for 1 egg and k floors for all k. If you have the information for n floors, and you have k+1 eggs, then for every n starting with n = 1 you have n choices where to drop an egg, with two outcomes with different probabilities and best of average cases that you know, and of the n choices you pick the best. Optimising the number of stairs walked is more difficult.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Are the question and answers reasonably different if we ask for the starting floor?

Comment: @Abdulgood89 Just add the floor that minimized the number to the return value, i.e. return a pair.

Comment: @Raphael Isn't this just a special case of the general problem? Perhaps I've misunderstood it.