# Search algorithm with at most a constant $k$ failed accesses

Tags: algorithms, runtime-analysis, search-algorithms

Let $A$ be an array sorted in non-increasing order. Let $m$ be a natural number. For example, let $m = 10$. We want to find the index $i$ such that $A[:i]$ contain elements less than or equal to $m$, whereas $A[i:]$ contain elements strictly greater than $m$.

We can easily do this using binary search in logarithmic time. However, consider the following variation. Each time we access an element strictly greater than $m$ is considered a 'failed access'. Assume we can only have at most $k$ failed accesses.

We could do a linear search in index order and then have at most 1 failed access. But this takes $\mathcal{O}(n)$ time which is slow.

I am trying to find a faster algorithm. For $k = 2$, I think we can get a $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n})$ algorithm by taking the squares of the indices, and then finding the first index where we get a failure. Then, do a linear search in the restricted range between the first failure, and the last non-failure. But I can't seem to find a fast algorithm for a general constant $k$.

Comment: Nice exercise!  Where did you encounter it?  Can you credit the original source where you ran across this?  What is the best you can come up with for $k=3$?

Comment: There are several questions on the site on the egg drop puzzle. Some of them include explicit algorithms.

Comment: I see now. The answer to this question is in the article [The Two Egg Problem](https://datagenetics.com/blog/july22012/index.html), that is mentioned in [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/65984/eggs-and-floors-puzzle-alternate).