# Egg dropping puzzle

Tags: algorithms

My problem is a modification of the known problem. Suppose you have a building with n floors.  (Where n can be any size). Furthermore you have an indestructible egg at your disposal.  If the egg is thrown from a floor which is not the maximum one gets a message. If the floor was too high you don't get a message. How can I design an algorithm that uses minimum many tests without knowing the height of the building? What is the minimum asymptotic runtime of such an algorithm?

Comment: "If the egg is thrown from a floor which is not the maximum one gets a message." Do you mean if the egg is not thrown from the $n^{th}$ floor, one gets a message? If you mean some floor is designated as the maximum floor, will there be a message or not if the egg is thrown on a floor lower than that maximum floor? Which floors are considered "too high"?

Comment: The known problem must be referring to something like [the problem of finding maximum number of floors you can check with N eggs and D maximum drops](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/64093/algorithm-to-find-maximum-number-of-floors-you-can-check-with-n-eggs-and-d-maxim)

Comment: I'm not sure your question is well-defined. What do you mean by *minimum number of tests*? For any given algorithm, the number of tests depends on the answer. Can you be more formal?

Comment: I can think of at least two reasonable models. Assuming that the number of floors is $n$ and that you throw the egg from floor $m$, you get to find out whether (1) $n=m$ or whether (2) $n<m$ (or $n \leq m$, which is the same). Which one is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that the true number of floors is $n$. Your question is unclear, but it seems that you are interested in the minimum number of queries of the form "$n < m$?" needed to find $n$.

Let us start with a lower bound. Consider a strategy for the task that works for every $n$. We can associate with each $n$ the transcript of the strategy, which is the list of yes/no answers to the queries performed by the strategy. These transcripts constitute a prefix code (why?), and so the number of queries $a_n$ asked when the answer is $n$ satisfies Kraft's inequality:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-a_n} \leq 1.
$$
In particular, $\limsup (a_n - \log n) = \infty$ (since the series $1/n$ diversges), which we write as $a_n \gg \log n$; here $\log n = \log_2 n$. Similarly, $a_n \gg \log n + \log \log n$ (since the series $1/n\log n$ diverges).

Let us now attempt to design strategies. One simple strategy asks whether $n < 2^t$ for $t=1,2,\ldots$, until finding a value of $t$ such that $2^t \leq n < 2^{t+1}$; this takes $\log n + O(1)$ queries. Binary search over $2^{t+1}$ takes $\log n + O(1)$ more queries, for a total of $2\log n + O(1)$.

A better strategy applies the above strategy recursively on the $t$'s. The first step is to ask whether $n < 2^{2^s}$ for $s=0,1,\ldots$, until finding a value of $s$ such that $2^{2^s} \leq n < 2^{2^{s+1}}$; this takes $\log \log n + O(1)$ queries. Binary search over $2^{2^s},2^{2^s+1},\ldots,2^{2^{s+1}}$ finds a value of $t$ such that $2^t \leq n < 2^{t+1}$ in $\log \log n + O(1)$ more steps, and finding $n$ using another binary search takes $\log n + O(1)$ steps, for a total of $\log n + 2\log\log n + O(1)$ steps.

The two strategies are completely analogous to Elias' [gamma coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elias_gamma_coding) and [delta coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elias_delta_coding). It is likely that Elias' [omega coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elias_omega_coding) can likewise be implemented.

Comment: See also https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/99331/683.