# Is there an asymptotically optimal algorithm for unbounded search?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory

Suppose you have files with size $1,2,3,4\dots$ (which can be arbitrarily large and which have and can have any value that you want) and a USB-stick whose memory size $s$ you don't know, where $s$ is a positive integer and can be arbitrarily large. If $s$ is not smaller than your current file you get a message that it would be possible to write the file on the USB-stick. If your current file is larger than $s$ then you get no message. In each time unit one file can be tested. My question is, is there an algorithm which finds $s$ in as few time units as possible and would this algorithm asymptotically optimal?

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Your question looks like interesting. However, $i_i$ looks like a typo. Do you mean the number of files is $i$? Suppose all we have are two files with 1MB and 5MB. Suppose the memory size is claimed to be 4MB. How can we verify that claim? If we want to talk about the asymptotic behavior, we have to specify infinitely many problems. I am not sure if I can spot them in the question.

Comment: @Apass.Jack Yes the number of files is i and $i_n$ means the size of file number $n$. I see it was a bit unclear. I meant that you also have abritrarily many files with ever memory size you want.

Comment: Instead of "a files with $i_1…i_n$ MB", it should simply be "files with $1, 2, 3, \cdots$ MB" (No article "a" before "files"). You can replace all references to $i_n$ by $n$.

Comment: If there is no bound to the memory size of USB, this problem cannot have a well-defined answer. Imagine your USB has 1 billion MB or a quadrillion MB or even more. There is no converging answer.

Comment: (I bet that you have not tried to solve your own question diligently. In fact, I have been in the same situation many times. When I had a new question, I was just thinking, this must be an interesting problem that is apparently beyond my reach. Let me just post my question to others to see if they can solve. Bang! I missed one condition. Bang! my question did not make sense.)

Comment: @Apass.Jack that was what i thought. You know that the memory is finit. For example if you first try to finde an upper bound for the USB stick with files of 
the size $1^2,2^2,3^2...$. Assume that $n^2$ is the first file of the form $x^2$ which is bigger than the USB stick. Than run binary search between  $(n-1)^2$ and $n^2$ . Obviously it would asymptotical better than just search with  $1,2,3,...$. But maybe when you start with $1^{2^2}...$ or $1!$ ect. it would be quicker?

Comment: If you believe testing by $1^2,2^2,3^2,...$ is better than $1,2,3,...$, you would also believe testing by $1^3,2^3,3^3...$ is better than $1^2,2^2,3^2,...$. You can go on like this forever. That is, there is no converging or correct answer. Some question just does NOT have an answer even if it sound like a well-defined question. Maybe I should write that as an answer, a meta-answer that says there is no proper answer.

Comment: Put it in another way, a proper answer will add an upper bound to the size of memory disk as well as the distribution of the size of the memory disk before stating what will be the best strategy to archive the least number of expected times needed to determine the size of the memory. Or something like that. Yes, your question is NOT as simple as you might have imagined. Or your question is more complex than you might have imagined.

Comment: We can also add a perspective of practicality to the question. That is, what we might do in real life to find the size by testing this way? Now we are (or I am) drifting away from computer science.

Comment: @Apass.Jack thank you for your answers, but i think you are wrong.  I have found something interesting about this. It seems this problem is related to this: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=009C752E0630EC1041116389CD716327?doi=10.1.1.135.604&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Congratulation on your persistence despite someone else (me) is indicating the other way. (In fact, I was planning to take a dive on exponentiation by 2. However, I felt I had spent too much time. I failed to persist.)

Comment: Can you summarize the result of that paper and write an answer? I can then upvote it. Once again, your insight and persistence is amazing.

Comment: I have tried my best to improve the question while preserving your style and keeping your last critical sentence intact. Please edit as you see fit.

Comment: I cannot understand the question. What is arbitrarily large? The number of files or the size of the files? And what is the actual target of the algorithm you are looking for? Are you probing for the storage capacity s of a usb inserting files of various sizes and waiting to see what message will pop up?

Comment: Were you inspired by [this recent questions](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/99294/egg-dropping-puzzle)?

Answer (score 1):

The basic observation is:

> **Lemma.** Suppose $a_s$ is a nondecreasing sequence of integers. There exists a strategy which uses $a_s$ queries when the answer is $s$ if and only if
>   $$ \sum_{s=1}^\infty 2^{-a_s} \leq 1. $$

In one direction, consider any strategy. For each $s$, let $w_s$ be the sequence of answers to queries made by the strategy. No word in the collection $\{w_s\}$ is a prefix of another, and so the collection forms a prefix code. The lengths $a_s = |w_s|$ therefore satisfy Kraft's inequality, $\sum_{s=1}^\infty 2^{-a_s} \leq 1$.

In the other direction, let us suppose that $\sum_{s=1}^\infty 2^{-a_s} \leq 1$. Decrease the $a_s$ if need be (while keeping them nondecreasing) so that $\sum_{s=1}^\infty 2^{-a_s} = 1$ (this is always possible); we can restore the original values later by asking dummy questions. Since the $a_s$ are nondecreasing, there is an index $S$ such that
$$ \sum_{s=1}^S 2^{-a_s} = \sum_{s=S+1}^\infty 2^{-a_s} = \frac{1}{2}. $$
The first question asked by the strategy is "$s \leq S$?". If the answer is affirmative, recurse on $a_1-1,\ldots,a_S-1$; otherwise, recurse on $a_{S+1}-1,\ldots$. The left recursion is different from the right recursion, since $a_1-1,\ldots,a_S-1$ is finite; but a similar argument works, with a base case of $a_1 = 0$, in which case no more questions need be asked. $\quad \square$

Given the lemma, we have reduced the question to the topic of the paper [universal codes of the natural numbers](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~yuvalf/UniversalCoding.pdf), in which it is shown that no optimal strategy exists (in a certain reasonable sense formalized in the paper).